# Executing Javascript function with first option of select element as soon as select element populates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload, onblur

I have a following select element:

```
<select id="options" title="prd_name" name="options">
  <option id='option1' value='Prdt1'>Product1</option>
  <option id='option2' value='Prdt2'>Product2</option>
  <option id='option3' value='Prdt3'>Product3</option>
  <option id='option4' value='Prdt4'>Product4</option>
</select>
```

I populate this select element using JQuery with some data from the database. I want to run a few Javascript functions as soon as this select element is populated with a options and I want those functions to run using the first option value. I am currently only able to run functions by adding **onblur** and **onchange** attributes in the **select tag**.

The problem arises, when I have only one option element, i.e. one product. By this I am unable to **onblur** or **onchange** and I used **onload** in the select element, which is not working aswell.

Anyone has any idea what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I would consider adding a background task `setInterval` that scans for changes if you cannot control under what circumstances this data will change and you need to respond to any/all of them.

Comment: In my opinion using an interval to check changes is a bad idea 'cause it doesn't have a good performance, creating custom events is the way to go IMHO

Comment: can u add your script code

Comment: I agree @AminJafari but it's also possible that OP has no control over the code that updates it (for whatever reason). Or that there are simply too many actions/possible entry points to modify all of them. This is basically how AngularJS (and most 2way binding framework solutions) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider calling the methods immediately after you populate the options , rather than triggering onblur / onchange.

Here is the code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //Consider this as success callback
      populateOptions();

    });

    function populateOptions(){
      var options = [1,2,3];
      var optionsHtml = "";
      for(var idx = 0; idx < options.length; idx++){
        var val = options[idx];
        optionsHtml += "<option id=option"+val+" value='Prdt"+val+"'>Product"+val+"</option>"
      }

      $("#firstDropdown").html(optionsHtml);

      executeMethods();
    }

    function executeMethods(){
      // find the first element
      var firstValue = $("#firstDropdown").find('option:eq(0)').val();
      if(firstValue === undefined){
        return;
      }

      console.log("Call Method with first Value : " + firstValue);
    }
```

jsbin : [Code Sample](http://jsbin.com/tayonuwaje/edit?html,css,console)

Answer (score 0):

imagine you have this data that you want to be populated into the select tag:

```
var _data=[
    {
    value:1,
    text:'one'
  },
    {
    value:2,
    text:'two'
  },
    {
    value:3,
    text:'three'
  },
    {
    value:4,
    text:'four'
  },
    {
    value:5,
    text:'five'
  }
];
```

you can create a custom event like this:

```
var selectPopulated=new Event('selectPopulated');
```

and then bind your event to your element like this:

```
  $('select').on('selectPopulated',function(){
    var firstOption=$(this).find('option:first-child').val();
    //your functions go here
    alert('Select is all populated - first option value is: '+firstOption);
  });
```

and then just trigger the event wherever you populate the select tag:

```
$('select').trigger('selectPopulated');
```

now you can even trigger this event in other js files without having to repeat your snippet only using the `trigger` method, here's a simple example: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ashdebbr/)**

and here's the complete code:

```
var _data=[
    {
    value:1,
    text:'one'
  },
    {
    value:2,
    text:'two'
  },
    {
    value:3,
    text:'three'
  },
    {
    value:4,
    text:'four'
  },
    {
    value:5,
    text:'five'
  }
];

var selectPopulated=new Event('selectPopulated');

function init(){
    $('select').on('selectPopulated',function(){
    var firstOption=$(this).find('option:first-child').val();
    //your functions go here
    alert('Select is all populated - first option value is: '+firstOption);
  });

    renderElements();
}

function renderElements(){
    var select=$('select');

  for(var i=0, dataLength=_data.length; i<dataLength; i++){
    select.append('<option value="'+_data[i].value+'">'+_data[i].text+'</option>');
  }
    $('select').trigger('selectPopulated');
}

init();
```

as pointed out in the comments by @PraneshRavi if you don't have control over how/when the element is getting populated the only possible way without having to change anything is to use an interval which is a bad idea but in the other hand if you do have control over the populating snippet I recommend creating an api where the code is populating the select and implementing the event method I just explained.

Answer (score -1):

You can call your functions after populating the `<select>` because appending elements into DOM is a synchronous activity.

Try this

```
function addOptions() {
   // do stuff to get the data from the database
  $('select').html() //adding options based on the data from the database into the <select>

  yourFunction(firstValue) //calling your functions
  yourFunction2()
}
addOptions()
```

Comment: The functions are written in Javascript and the selector is in JQuery. Please could you guide me as to the how to call Javascript functions using JQuery selectors.

Comment: @UmarAbbasKhan you don't need to call your JavaScript function using jquery selector. Just call your JavaScript function right after you populate the <select> tag with the options from the database. This should work